# Turfjs default es6 import fails

Tags: javascript, mapbox-gl-js

I'm trying to use Turf `distance` and Turf `point` with Mapbox GL JS.

I've installed @turf/distance from npm which also installs @turf/helpers.

I see that `distance` has a default export

```
exports.default = distance;
```

So my import is as follows:

```
import distance from '@turf/distance';
import { point } from '@turf/helpers';
```

`point` imports as expected, `distance` is always empty, whatever I try.
This should be so simple....

Can anybody put me out of my misery, and tell me how they imported `distance`?

UPDATE: found the problem

I was reassigning the `distance` variable - what a noob.

```
let distance = distance(from, to, options);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm sorry to say that that should *just work*.

I have a project with Turf loaded, and just added:

```
import distance from '@turf/distance'

...

console.log("DISTANCE IS: ", distance)
```

And I get this logged on the console:

[image: Distance function is logged]

What this means is that it seems to work fine to import that way. Maybe check your code somewhere else.

Comment: Ok, it's good at least to have it confirmed that I am not going mad. I think I shall trash node_modules and do a fresh npm install and see if that helps

Comment: I've updated my question with the solution. I've given you the answer because your confirmation that I wasn't doing anything wrong with the import helped a lot.